# How to compute zonal statistics fast?

Tags: arcpy, performance, software-recommendations, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I have 12000 circles with a radius of 50 miles on a raster with 0.05 degree resolution. Global analysis. The raster is 32 bit float and I have to calculate zonal statistics for 20 different rasters. Each calculation takes approximately 6 hours in QGIS on my local machine (16GB RAM, 4 cores i7, windows OSGeo4W suite). Looking for best ways to speed up. I do have limited knowledge of spinning up cloud instances with Linux. Options are:

- multiprocessing on local machine
- Linux instances with rasterstats (running into problems while installing on Linux instance using pip)
- Linux instances with QGIS toolbox (having problems calling the processing toolbox. Zonal stats by QGIS is preferred over the SAGA one)
- Linux instances with other tools/libraries??
- Windows server with ArcPy capabilities

What flavour to choose? I'm using Python 2.7 as scripting language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run a benchmark test between QGIS and [`pktools`](http://pktools.nongnu.org/html/index.html) and specifically [`pkextract`](http://pktools.nongnu.org/html/pkextract.html) (*extract pixel values from raster image from a (vector or raster*) sample) to see if it is faster when run directly from the command-line. The usage of the tool is outlined on the above-mentioned link, but in general terms it is:

```
pkextract -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -s vector_aoi.shp -i input_raster.tif 
-o output_vector_with_stats.shp -polygon --rule mean
```

Note `pkextract` provides a set of rules that include: centroid, mean, stdev, median, proportion, count, min, max, mode, sum, percentile

`pktools` can be installed on Debian using `apt-get` or using the [pkools_install_script](http://pktools.nongnu.org/html/md_installation_linux.html#installation_linux) on Ubuntu and other Unix distributions.

If you need to speed this process up, consider using `xargs` on linux.

Comment: It works. I am the using subprocess module in python with shell=true to get the results